# Redirection in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a small question regarding rails. I have a search controller which searches for a name in database, if found shows the details about it or else I am redirecting to the new name page. Is there anyway after redirection that the name searched for to automatically appear in the new form page?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [ActionController::Flash](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Flash.html) to pass data between actions.

```
def search(searchedName)
  # perform search on DB

  flash[:searchedName] = searchedName

  redirect_to new_name
end

def new_name
end
```

new_name.html.erb:

```
<% if flash[:searchedName] %>
  <%= text_field_tag flash[:searchedName] %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Nice. But how do I set this in that particular text field in the next page?

Comment: @Cyborgo: added snippet for view to set text box content with passed data

Answer (score 2):

Well, let's say you are saving this 'name' entered by user on a variable named @name.
So, on the controller that do the action of search, you did something like:

```
if @name
  ...#action if the name was found
else
  session[:name] = @name
  ...#here is the action you did to redirect
```

On the declaration of the method called (you said it was 'new') :

```
def new
  @name = session[:name] if session[:name]  #I don't know exactly if the condition is this one, 
                                             #but you have to confirm that the session was instatiated
  session.delete(:name) #to don't let garbage
  ...#continuous the action of show the new page
     #and on the page you have access to a variable @name, that have the name searched before.
```

Comment: I believe it's just `if session[:name]`